# Blazor: Detect when component is shown in the screen

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

Let's say I have a blazor component that uses a lot of resources to create an animation, it doesn't make sense to keep rendering it if the user scroll past the component (i.e. the component not visible in the screen). Is there a way to detect this using Blazor?

I am aware that I can rely on [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) with JS, but I am looking for something in Blazor/C#.

Thanks,

Comment: I don’t believe that there is any built-in method like this. You can use the JavaScript interop to utilize the Intersection Observer API for this though.

Comment: The answer is : Nope

Comment: You can use https://github.com/ljbc1994/BlazorIntersectionObserver which is a wrapper around the Intersection Observer API, has support for .NET 5.

Comment: @ljbc1994, amazing; this is what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @ljbc1994 I would honestly transform your comment in an answer, perhaps with a code example -- this package is saving my life ATM, and I could only find it because I checked the comments. Great work!